# Daily visit/session count of each user on google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to see daily session count of each users on Google Analytics.
I have already enabled user-id and I can see total session count of each user.
But I need daily session count of each user on a given period of time

Comment: Not a direct answer but you can get an average using a Cohort Analysis -> Change the Metric to Sessions per User.

Comment: I'm not sure if it exactly meets your needs, but that sounds like what the frequency and recency report does: https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2282540/how-to-use-the-google-analytics-frequency-recency-report